# Xamarin Forms need help to print through bluetooth printer XP200

Tags: printing, xamarin.forms, bluetooth, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm creating an XF application which can connect to a printer(XP200) through bluetooth. I've read a lot of topic regarding to "how to access bluetooth device/ use barcode scanner" and also try to implement BluetoothLE package. But the problem is I'm using .Net standard 2.0 so that packages didn't work correctly. I'm finding another solution in this case and that would be great if anyone already worked with XPrinter could help me. Thanks in advance guys

Comment: what packages did you try to install ? isnt the BLE native apis enough ?

Comment: @RanSasportas yes, I tried it but my printer is a dual device. I tried with bluetooth socket and it can connect to the device but another problem came, my device only support for using its SDK. I couldn't know how to work with it